# Any way to have initial delay for PeriodicWorkRequest

Tags: android, android-workmanager

For `OneTimeWorkRequest`, we can have `setInitialDelay` to specific the initial delay.

However, there isn't such facility for `PeriodicWorkRequest`.

**Is there any reliable way to achieve so?**

One of the less reliable way, is to have a delayed `OneTimeWorkRequest` worker, to setup `PeriodicWorkRequest`. However, that's quite cumbersome, and create a possibility, where `OneTimeWorkRequest` may fail and not able to install `PeriodicWorkRequest`.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `androidx.work:work-*:2.1.0`, `PeriodicWorkRequests` support initial delays. You can use the `setInitialDelay` method on `PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder` to set an initial delay.

See [link](https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/androidx/releases/work) for official documentation.

Comment: `setInitialDelay` works weird. When I set a startup period of 15 minutes and the initial delay of 1 minute, the worker starts after 16 minutes. I thought it would immediately (as `OneTimeWorkRequest`), but after 1 minute (and not after 16 minutes). And the subsequent starts will be every 15 minutes.

Comment: @proninyaroslav Looks like it executes at the end of the interval, not at the beginning

Answer (score 5):

Since the system runs your work you can't control the exact time it will run..

Your best option for creating a work execution delay is to use this `PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder` and supply a `flexInterval` as the 4th parameter:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest build = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
     SyncJobWorker.class, 
     REPEAT_INTERVAL, // repeatInterval
     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, // repeatIntervalTimeUnit
     FLEX_INTERVAL, // flexInterval
     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // flexIntervalTimeUnit
       .build();
```

Docs ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#periodicworkrequestbuilder_2

> Creates a PeriodicWorkRequest to run periodically once within the flex period of every interval period. See diagram below. The flex period begins at intervalMillis - flexMillis to the end of the interval. intervalMillis must be greater than or equal to PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS and flexMillis must be greater than or equal to PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_FLEX_MILLIS.

[image]

Comment: Beware.  Also from the docs:  `Note that flex intervals are ignored for certain OS versions (in particular, API 23).`  Also note that the minimum flex time, PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_FLEX_MILLIS, is 5 minutes.