# JobScheduler executes after every 15 min

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I am using JobScheduler in my application. I want to upload file after every hour if user connected to WIFI, but `onStartJob()`method gets called before hour, mostly it gets called after 15-20 min. Following is my code :

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this,UploadService.class);
    JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(1,componentName)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED) // change this later to wifi
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setPeriodic(60*60*10000)
            .build();

    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
    if (resultCode==JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG,"JOb Scheduled");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"Job Scheduling fail");
    }

public class UploadService extends JobService {
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    uploadFileToServer(params);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return true;
}
.....
.....
}
```

Here `uploadFileToServer(params);` gets called before hour. how to set time so it will call only after hour. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have switched to Work Manager due to issues of Job Scheduler, Also Job Scheduler need android 21. Have a look on Work Manager available for all versions.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: how does your `jobFinished` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method `setPeriodic (long intervalMillis, long flexMillis)` (**Added in API 24**) on the `JobInfo.Builder` and supply a flex interval as the 2nd parameter:

```
long flexMillis = 59 * 60 * 1000; // wait 59 minutes before executing next job    

JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(1,componentName)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED) // change this later to wifi
        .setPersisted(true)
        .setPeriodic(60 * 60 * 1000, flexMillis)
        .build();
```

**Importent** - The job is guaranteed to run after the flex interval (which starts after the last job is finished), but it's not guaranteed to run immediately after that time, so the duration between jobs can be more than 1 hour, depending on your job requirements, system status, and more...

Docs ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPeriodic(long,%20long)

> Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval and flex. The job can execute at any time in a window of flex length at the end of the period.

[image: Illustration]

---

As already recommended in some comments, you should start working with the new [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) (even that it's not production level yet) which has similar features as the `JobScheduler`, but it's minimum SDK support is 14 which will let you delete a lot of boilerplate code :)

Comment: Thanks for explanation, after some time I will test this and let u know the same.

Comment: Its added in 
added in API level 24
and I have to support 
 API level 21

Comment: You are right, but that's your only option with the `JobScheduler`.. You can achieve this behaviour with the `WorkManager`, here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229826/any-way-to-have-initial-delay-for-periodicworkrequest/51229868#51229868

Comment: I am using WorkManager for this.

Answer (score 0):

From the JobInfo.java class ,
**You have no control over when within this interval this job will be executed**

```
    /**
     * Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval, not more than once per
     * period. You have no control over when within this interval this job will be executed,
     * only the guarantee that it will be executed at most once within this interval.
     * Setting this function on the builder with {@link #setMinimumLatency(long)} or
     * {@link #setOverrideDeadline(long)} will result in an error.
     * @param intervalMillis Millisecond interval for which this job will repeat.
     */
    public Builder setPeriodic(long intervalMillis) {
        return setPeriodic(intervalMillis, intervalMillis);
    }
```